# Ember: Back button broken

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a simple web app using Ember. I am rendering a nested resource into the application template rather than it's parent resource.

This works fine except if I press the back button I go back to the parent resource but the parent template is not rendered into the application outlet. I can refresh the page and bingo it renders then.

Router:

```
Movies.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('list', { path: '/list' }, function() {
    this.route('add');
    // Nested resource example
    this.resource('movies', { path: '/:list_id/movies' }, function() {
    });
  });

  this.route('boxoffice');
});
```

Movies Route:

```
Movies.MoviesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Movies.List.find(params.list_id);
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('movies', {
      // template outlet to render into (will mess up your back btn!)
      into: 'application'
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I *think* you'll have to also inform the `outlet` in [`Route#renderTemplate`'s `render`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) call

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - do you mean specify a named outlet?

Answer (score 2):

By default the ember Router uses the browser's hash to load routes of your application and will keep it in sync. This relies on a hashchange event existing in the browser.
But you can setup ember to use the browser `history` API instead of `hash` which is the default. This can be accomplished in different way's. For example like this:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location : Ember.Location.create({
    implementation : 'history' // can be hash, history or none
  })
});
```

Or by a more simpler approach by reopening the router like this:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

This way using the browser back & forward buttons would work as expected.
For more info on the history API see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/).

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work for me. Same result using the history API.